# Any way to get a reference to "this" in a generated iterator block?

Tags: c#, iterator, extension-methods

Since C# 2.0 we've been able to declare iterator blocks inside classes and return values from them using the `yield return` keywords.  Behind the scenes the compiler has generously converted our rather simple iterator block into its own class, a state machine which fully implements either the `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerator` interface.  Using ILSpy or Reflector you can get a glimps of what these classes look like.

In C# 3.5 Extension Methods were added to the language providing a simple means of writing static methods that will appear in existing classes or interfaces' intellisense popup.

What I am interested in doing is combining these two concepts and in doing so I'm having a difficult time.  My frustration centers around the fact that in an iterator block, the `this` keyword refers to the class that the iterator block is in instead of the compiler generated class which holds the implementation of the iterator block.

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
public static class IteratorExtensions
{
    public static void DoSomething<T>(this IEnumerable<T> iterator)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Running iterator block of type :" + typeof(T).Name);
    }
}

public class IteratorExample
{
    public IEnumerable<string> MyIterator()
    {
        yield return "Hello";
        this.DoSomething();
        yield return "World";
    }
}
```

Unfortunately in this context `this` refers to an instance of IteratorExample and not to an instance of the generated MyIterator class.  Is there any way to get a reference in the iterator or will I have to rethink my plans?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What exactly is `DoSomething`? The way iterator blocks are implemented shouldn't be visible to you, so I think you can't do this, but you may be able to do what you actually want to achieve, if you tell us what that is.

Comment: This sounds like an abuse of the system. The state-machine class is an implementation detail, and I don't think you should be relying on it. There's a good chance there's an easier way to do what you want anyway; perhaps you can tell us what that is?

Comment: I'm not wanting to see the implementation details, I'm wanting to write extension methods against it's interface.  This sample code was just that, a sample.  I'd imagine this would be most useful to write extension methods against specific types of iterators, for example, extension methods where `this` is `IEnumerable<ITask<T>>` would allow you to write extension methods scoped to iterators of the ITask interface objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No clean way, no. All `this` usage is intercepted and refers to the *declaring* instance.

You could *possibly* do something horrible involving abusing the stack or similar, but nothing tidy is obvious. You could maybe *chain* the iterators LINQ-style instead? i.e.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WithLogging<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    source.DoSomething();
    try {
        foreach(var item in source) yield return item;
    } finally {
        source.DoSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

and use `originalIterator.WithLogging()`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are going to be able to do what you want-- I think the language spec hides the implementation class so it doesn't constrain future implementations of the same feature that might use a different mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work, so you will have to rethink your plans.

If you give more information about what you want to achieve we might be able to help you find an alternative solution.